# Package Installation From GitHub Error - Possibly File Path

Tags: r

I am currently trying to install some packages off of GitHub, but I keep on getting this fatal error. I think it has something to do with the file destination, but I am unsure. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
> devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/albersusa")
Downloading GitHub repo hrbrmstr/albersusa@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\FirstName Surname\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeqCuBA\remotes51a46de62be1\hrbrmstr-albersusa-5b933bf/DESCRIPTION' (489ms)
-  preparing 'albersusa':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'albersusa_0.3.1.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/FirstName Surname/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'albersusa' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\FirstName': No such file or directory

ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'albersusa'
* removing 'C:/Users/FirstName Surname/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/albersusa'
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/FirstName Surname/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeqCuBA/file51a45f6e3a8b/albersusa_0.3.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The packages should be installed into ‘C:/Users/FirstName Surname/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’ as it says it is doing, however it gives the fatal error when it encounters: 'C:\Users\FirstName' which is different.

Edit: Windows 10, R-3.6.0, RStudio

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `.libpaths()` to change the installation directory or simply run it and see where packages are being installed. Does that folder actually exist?

Comment: @NelsonGon hey! Yeah, when I run that it gives me the ‘C:/Users/FirstName Surname/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’ as the primary option (this is where all of my packages are normally stored), however the fatal error seems to occur for 'C:\Users\FirstName', which I assume is different.

Comment: Try changing it. Not sure why or how it was changed. Let me try installing it.

Comment: @NelsonGon What should I change it to? I don't think (although I am unsure) that the error occurs when it is finding the initial path to store the package, ‘C:/Users/FirstName Surname/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’, it only seems to dislike return the error when it tries to open 'C:\Users\FirstName'. I don't know why it is trying to open that path though as I never told it to and it doesn't exist.

Comment: This is the problem `'C:\Users\FirstName'`, it should either be double backward slashes or a single forward slash. I don't know if it's the package as I'm still trying to download it.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the problem - thanks! It is something I hadn't seen before, it happens with just a few packages but it seems to want to open 'C:\Users\FirstName' instead of where the file was actually placed.

Comment: This is due to the white space in the path. I would try `install_github("hrbrmstr/albersusa", lib = shortPathName(.libPaths()[1]))`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Hey! So I attempted to do as you suggested, but got the same error. I think your suspicion about the space in the path is correct, but I can't change it as this is a work laptop. Any other workarounds?

Comment: Hmm probably the short path name is expanded, and then is useless. One workaround consists in installing in another folder (with the `lib` argument), and then copy-paste the created `albersusa` folder to your usual library folder (the one with the white space). Another option: clone the github repo, or download and extract the zip, and install the package with RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the r package to 4.0.1 version solved this issue